# Is there way to create a dynamic title header in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am pretty new at amCharts and have been tasked with creating an incredibly challenging chart. On the of the features of this chart is to have a dynamic title for each each chart where the period selector from and to dates appear in text form within and the title and also change as the period.

Is there somebody on this forum that has alot of experience on this awesome charting system, that could give me some guidelines.

I understand that it would have to be an "addlistener" event, but am not sure how I would make that work within the chart.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about baloon text that apear over bars? Can you share some more information about what you want?

Comment: Hi Djordje  thank you for coming back to me. I was was not taking about the balloons wehat I was asking how I would go about pulling the dates from the period selector in the chart title. Since this post I have figured that part out, I would appreciate some guidance though in how I would pull the zooming part of the chart to show the changed dates to in the header. So as the you zoom the chart with the scrollbars ther changed date appears in the title.